# Where is the data loaded after scrolling saved in instagram search

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a python script which logs into Instagram then navigates to the search page and looks for a hashtag. After search results appears, Selenium starts scrolling down to get more data until it reaches the condition to stop scrolling. However, when I save the page source in BeautiFul Soup Objects I only get the results which were loaded on page load NOT the one's loaded after scrolling down.. How can i get the data loaded after scrolling? I tried looking in the source and searched all over the internet but still I'm unable to get all records.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does _save the page source in BeautiFul Soup Objects_ mean? When are you getting the source?

Comment: when scrolling ends bsObj = BeautifulSoap(driver.page_source)

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285070/driver-doesnt-return-proper-page-source

Comment: thanks a lot that link helped me resolve the issue